# C# the way "Return" works

Tags: c#

In the code below, why does the return value not equal 1? From the output I can see that the method returns cab to the main code with the return value 1, but the return value is 6, which is what the example says it should be, but I can't understand why.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
     class Program
    {

        static int fact(int num)
        {
            if(num==1)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("num = 1x");
                return 1;
                Console.WriteLine("xx");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("num = " + num);
            return num * fact(num - 1);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Console.WriteLine(fact(3));


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because its recursive.. so you send it 3, so it calls fact(3), fact(2), fact(1) adds them all together and that fact 3 returns to you basically fact(3)*fact(2)*fact(1) .. which is right. if you followed it in debug, you'd see fact(1) does return 1..

Comment: The question is not related to return in any way, it is just simple recursion.

Comment: fact(3)
num = 3
num = 2
num = 1x
6
----------
fact(1)
num = 1x
1